# Get list of used path segments in controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When dynamically creating routes for a Rails application, how can one know which path segments are used in a request?

The request’s `params` hash holds the used path segments and their values, but it also contains other things. This makes it impossible to know which keys in the `params` hash are the ones of path segments.

**Example**: The following dynamically creates routes (e.g. `/photos/:photoId`) in my application:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.append do
  routes.values.each do |route|
    get "/#{route['path']}" => 'routes#show'
  end
end
```

Is there any way one can retrieve the segments used for a route in a controller’s action?

Alternatively, can one pass additional arguments to a controller action?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to differentiate the params that are part of the request url (for example, the `id` in a url like `/photos/:id`) from the rest of the request params?

Comment: @ldeld Yes. From `request.params`, I only want the objects that come from dynamic path segments. Also, I just found out that one can indeed pass custom arguments to controller actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that one can add arbitrary arguments to controller actions like this:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.append do
  routes.values.each do |route|
    get "/#{route['path']}" => 'routes#show', segments: route['segments']
  end
end
```

I assumed this wasn’t the case because it wasn’t mentioned anywhere in the article ["Rails Routing from the Outside In"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

---

This is not ideal as it requires me to store the segments along with my route objects. It would be preferable to have Rails provide a *segments* hash containing both dynamic and wildcard path segments.